# Animating over a background image

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, drawing

I have created a window that has a large JPanel occupying the greater part of the area that will be used to animate a set of fireworks. I have a private inner class AnimationPanel which extends JPanel. I have overridden paintComponent() in order to use a buffered image as a background. Upon pressing the start button, a simulation will run which will animate the set of fireworks. Right now, this simulation outputs the positions to the console, and generates a collection called snapshot containing all of the fireworks at a particular point in time.

At the moment, I have successfully drawn the background and a small rectangle to represent the launch tube, but when I try to paint the fireworks from the snapshot, nothing shows up. At this point I am not concerned about animation (still learning how to do this using the Timer class), but I need to know that the draw will work, so I am just trying to draw the snapshot. I am repainting animationPanel at the end of the simulation after getting the snapshot.

The private inner class AnimationPanel

```
private class AnimationPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage background;

    public AnimationPanel() {
        super();
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg"));
        } catch(IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this); //this shows up
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()-30, 10, 30); //this shows up
        paintFireWorks(g); //this doesn't show up
    }

    private void paintFireWorks(Graphics g) {
        if(snapshot != null) {
            for(Firework item: snapshot) {
                double[] position = item.getPosition();
                if(item instanceof Star){
                    int x = (int)Math.round(position[0])+animationPanel.getWidth()/2;
                    int y = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1]);
                    int r = ((Star) item).getRenderSize();
                    g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
                } else if(item instanceof Spark){
                    int x1 = (int)Math.round(position[0])+animationPanel.getWidth()/2;
                    int x2 = (int)Math.round(position[0])-((Spark)item).getRenderSize();
                    int y1 = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1]);
                    int y2 = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1])+((Spark)item).getRenderSize();
                    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The entire FireWorksWindow class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FireWorksWindow extends JFrame {

//DIMENSIONS AND POSITIONS
private final int STARTING_POS_X = 1600;
private final int STARTING_POS_Y = 100;

//CONTAINERS AND COMPONENTS
private AnimationPanel animationPanel;
private JPanel controlPanel, sliderPanel;
private Box controlBox;
private JLabel windSliderLabel, angleSliderLabel;
private JSlider windSpeed, launchAngle;
private JButton startButton, pauseButton, exitButton;

//TIMER
private Timer animationTimer;

//COLLECTIONS
ArrayList<Particle> fireworks;
ArrayList<Particle> snapshot;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public FireWorksWindow() {
    setTitle("Roman Candle Animation");
    setLocation(STARTING_POS_X,STARTING_POS_Y);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    sliderPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout sliderGrid = new GridBagLayout();
    sliderPanel.setLayout(sliderGrid);
    initSliders();
    initLabels();
    addComponent(sliderGrid, windSliderLabel,       1,1,new Insets(5,10,5,10));
    addComponent(sliderGrid, angleSliderLabel,      1,2,new Insets(5,10,5,10));
    addComponent(sliderGrid, windSpeed,             2,1,new Insets(5,10,5,10));
    addComponent(sliderGrid, launchAngle,           2,2,new Insets(5,10,5,10));

    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controlPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    initButtons();
    initControlBox();
    controlPanel.add(controlBox);
    controlPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.MAGENTA , 3 ));

    animationPanel = new AnimationPanel();
    animationPanel.setSize(new Dimension(750,500));
    animationPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(animationPanel.getWidth(),animationPanel.getHeight()));
    animationPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(animationPanel.getWidth(),animationPanel.getHeight()));

    add(animationPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(),getHeight()));
    sliderPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(sliderPanel.getWidth(), sliderPanel.getHeight()));
}

//CONVENIENCE METHODS
private void addComponent(GridBagLayout layout, Component component, int row, int column, Insets padding) {
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = column;
    constraints.gridy = row;
    constraints.insets = padding;
    layout.setConstraints(component, constraints);
    sliderPanel.add(component);
}

private void initLabels() {
    windSliderLabel = new JLabel("Wind Speed");
    angleSliderLabel = new JLabel("Launch Angle");
}

private void initSliders() {
    windSpeed = new JSlider(-20,20);
        windSpeed.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        windSpeed.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        windSpeed.setPaintTicks(true);
        windSpeed.setPaintLabels(true);
    launchAngle = new JSlider(-15,15);
        launchAngle.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        launchAngle.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        launchAngle.setPaintTicks(true);
        launchAngle.setPaintLabels(true);
}

private void initButtons() {
    startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.addActionListener(new StartHandler());
    pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
    pauseButton.addActionListener(new PauseHandler());
    exitButton  = new JButton("Exit" );
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
}

private void initControlBox() {
    controlBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    controlBox.add(sliderPanel);
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
    controlBox.add(startButton);
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    controlBox.add(pauseButton);
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    controlBox.add(exitButton);
    controlBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
}

//ACTION LISTENERS
public class WindAdjustListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}

public class AngleAdjustListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}

public class StartHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("START Pressed");
        startButton.setText("Reset");
        repaint();
        runAnimation();
        startButton.setText("Start");
    }
}

public class PauseHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("PAUSE Pressed");
    }
}

public class ExitHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(animationTimer != null)
            if(animationTimer.isRunning())
                animationTimer.stop();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class AnimationClock implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }   
}

//ACCESSORS
public double[] getSliderValues() {
    double[] sliders = new double[2];
    sliders[0] = windSpeed.getValue();
    sliders[1] = launchAngle.getValue();
    return sliders;
}

//OTHER METHODS
public void runAnimation() {
    double[] inputs = getSliderValues();
    double wind = inputs[0];
    double launchAngle = inputs[1];
    double timeInterval = 0.05;     // seconds
    ParticleManager manager = null;
    try {
        manager = new ParticleManager(wind, launchAngle);
    } catch (EnvironmentException except) {
        System.out.println(except.getMessage());
        return;
    } catch (EmitterException except) {
        System.out.println(except.getMessage());            
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Counts:");
    System.out.println("time\tStars\tSparks\tLaunchSparks");
    double time = 0;
    manager.start(time);
    fireworks = manager.getFireworks(time);
    do {
        //if (time % 0.5 == 0)
            showTypesCount(fireworks, time);
        if (Math.abs(time - 2.0) < timeInterval)
            snapshot = fireworks;
        time += timeInterval;
        fireworks = manager.getFireworks(time);
    } while (fireworks.size() > 0);
    showFireworks(snapshot, 2.0);
    animationPanel.repaint();
}

public void showFireworks(ArrayList<Particle> fireworks, double time) {
    if (fireworks == null)
        return;
    System.out.printf("\nAt time%5.2f seconds:\n", time);
    System.out.println("Type\t\tPosition (metres)");
    for (Particle firework : fireworks)
        System.out.println(firework);
}

public void showTypesCount(ArrayList<Particle> fireworks, double time) {
    int starCount = 0;
    int sparkCount = 0;
    int launchSparkCount = 0;
    for (Particle firework : fireworks) {
        if (firework instanceof Star)
            starCount++;
        else if (firework instanceof LaunchSpark)
            launchSparkCount++;
        else
            sparkCount++;
    }
    System.out.printf("%5.2f\t", time);
    System.out.println(starCount + "\t" + sparkCount + "\t" + launchSparkCount);
}

private class AnimationPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage background;

    public AnimationPanel() {
        super();
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg"));
        } catch(IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this); //this shows up
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()-30, 10, 30); //this shows up
        paintFireWorks(g); //this doesn't show up
    }

    private void paintFireWorks(Graphics g) {
        if(snapshot != null) {
            for(Firework item: snapshot) {
                double[] position = item.getPosition();
                if(item instanceof Star){
                    int x = (int)Math.round(position[0])+animationPanel.getWidth()/2;
                    int y = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1]);
                    int r = ((Star) item).getRenderSize();
                    g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
                } else if(item instanceof Spark){
                    int x1 = (int)Math.round(position[0])+animationPanel.getWidth()/2;
                    int x2 = (int)Math.round(position[0])-((Spark)item).getRenderSize();
                    int y1 = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1]);
                    int y2 = animationPanel.getHeight()-(int)Math.round(position[1])+((Spark)item).getRenderSize();
                    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any ideas as to why the fireworks drawings are not showing up? I have tried to adapt to the methods shown in this answer ([Dynamic Graphics Object Painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628492/dynamic-graphics-object-painting/10628553#10628553)) and this one ([panel with image background and mouse draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102076/panel-with-image-background-and-mouse-draw?lq=1)), but have had no success. Still stuck with a background and a rectangle.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Absolutely will do so from now on - thanks for the links on the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this...

```
public class StartHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("START Pressed");
        startButton.setText("Reset");
        repaint();
        runAnimation();
        startButton.setText("Start");
    }
}
```

You are calling `runAnimation` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

In you `runAnimation` method you then do this...

```
do {
   //...
} while (fireworks.size() > 0);
```

Which is block the EDT and preventing from processing new events, including repaint requests

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

A simple solution would be to use a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which would allow you offload a small wait into the background but which is triggered within the context of the EDT...

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I was more interested in getting the drawing of a particular instant than animating at this point though. As it turns out, the reason the drawing wasn't showing up was because I wasn't converting the heights properly, which I discovered shortly after this posting. I can now see my drawings. Sorry for the time wasted.