# Why is the paintComponent method called twice?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm working on an app where I draw everything pixel by pixel. During the process, I noticed that the `paintComponent()` method of a certain `JPanel` is called twice. So I created the following *MCVE* to figure out whether it has something to do with the other components being drawn to the screen, or if it's just a standalone issue:

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame("Paint test"));
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private Board mBoard;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mBoard = new Board();
        add(mBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Board.java**

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        System.out.println("CALLED");
    }
}
```

But the console log shows `"CALLED"` twice.

I'm specifically interested in `paintComponent()` since it's the method where all of the app's magic works, so I need to control each draw cycle.

*What are the reasons behind this double call to `paintComponent()` ?*

Is there another way I could do my drawings some other way **once** ? (I mean, not in `paintComponent()`, if it would be called twice no matter what)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is my code executing paintComponent(Graphics page) twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814289/why-is-my-code-executing-paintcomponentgraphics-page-twice)

Comment: Hey @BackSlash , thanks for the link but I've already checked it out (& the link mentionned within it). In that post, it's stated that it's an OS thing, but **I need to control that behavior.**

Comment: You can put println statements in the MainFrame constructor to verify, but I suspect the add method and the setVisible method cause a JPanel repaint.  You cause a repaint when you minimize and maximize the JFrame.  You have no control over the paintComponent method.  That's why you do nothing but paint in the paintComponent method.  You perform calculations elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't think painting is done on invisible components, or am I wrong?

Comment: For me the above code prints only once. Win 7 Java 1.8.0_25.

Comment: @user1803551 as stated in the *"maybe-is-an-answer"*, the behavior is **OS-specific**. (Win 10, Java 1.8 too)

Comment: Is [*double buffering*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#db) enabled?

Comment: A component might be painted a number of times in quick succession when it's first displayed for a number of reasons. A lot will come down to how the native peer is initialised and prepared and how the layout is invalidated and updated when the window is finally realised and made visible. The fact is, you really shouldn't care

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Unless explicitly set otherwise, double buffering is enabled by default

Comment: Yes, I saw, but what it shows is that you can't control this (unless you do some hefty native code stuff I guess). It's going to be difficult to answer *why* is happens. Do you intent to redirect your question? Note that you shouldn't do heavy calculations inside `paintComponent`, the call should return quickly.

Comment: On MaxOSX, Java 8, it only gets called once when initialising the screen

Comment: In that case, I must have got it all wrong. Since I'm doing lots of calculations & drawings inside... & I really need to control that initial, *"first appearance on stage"* behavior of the panel.

Comment: Are the heavy calculations done only for the initial  display or throughout the applications life? Is the initial state dependent on launch parameters (`String[] args`)?

Comment: These calculations are independent of anything else... just to explain myself more, this is a tic tac toe game. So I'm basically drawing rectangles inside rectangles inside other rectangles... but the problem is, that since `paintComponent` is called twice, some of the game's logic is executed twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the paintComponent method called twice?

Because it is called whenever the plug-in determines it is needed.

> **I need to control that behavior.**

Better to use an approach that works, rather than chase an end that cannot be achieved.

The logical approach to this conundrum though, is to instead draw everything to a `BufferedImage` that is displayed in (an `ImageIcon` that is displayed in) a `JLabel`.  Then no matter how many times the `repaint()` method of the label is called, the app. still only needs to generate the pixels once.

### Examples

1. [Draw in an image inside panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037856/418556)

   [image]
2. [Multiple calls of paintComponent()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15891660/418556)

   [image]
3. [Drawing the Cannabis Curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799711/418556)

   [image]

Comment: The 2nd example, totally what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After reading the short discussion in the comments I have a suggestion. Prepare the `Shape` object and save it as a resource. This will save the runtime calculations. When the program launches, load the file in a separate thread (parallel to loading the GUI) and then just paint that object. Doing just the painting shouldn't be expensive so even if it's called several times there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'll give it a shot in 16 hours, & get back to you. (phone mode ON)

Comment: The `Graphics` object passed to your `paintComponent` is a shared resource, it's used by all the components within the current window to paint onto, you should NEVER maintain a reference to it (or `dispose` it), this is not how painting is done.  If needed use a `BufferedImage`, also remember, Swing is NOT thread safe, so you should ALWAYS ensure that the UI (or any part of the UI) is updated only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oops. Thanks, updated. I said `Graphics` but was thinking about the `Shape` painted by it. I remember doing that a few years ago and it worked fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: As long as the actually painting is done within the context of the EDT and through the appropriate paint methods, yes. Just beware that when the shape is been painted, you should not be changing the shape

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't think that shape is going to change based on the OP's comment. If it does need to change, it can be from the EDT before painting it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer BTW, you shouldn't be shy of downvoting (my) bad answers. De/Serializing `Graphics` objects in this context certainly deserves one.

Comment: I'm just hoping to pull you (kicking and screaming) to a better one ;)

Comment: *"Prepare the `Shape` object and save it as a resource."* It can be tricky to serialize a `Shape`.  See [How to serialize Java 2D Shape objects as XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26579729/418556) for tips.