# produce a plot with multiple points in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

I do not have much familiar with graphics in Java, sorry. However, this is what I'm trying to do. I want to be able draw a couple of points on a canvas (JPanel here), and be able to redraw the points everytime the method (drawPoints) is invoked with a new set of parameters: double[]xs, double[]ys. Any chance I could do this without 'redrawing' the canvas? I can't even get the points to plot in the current state of the code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class PlotPoints extends JPanel {    
double[] x;
double[] y;

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)     
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d  = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        g2d.fillOval((int)this.x[i],(int)this.y[i], 10, 10);            
    }
}

public void drawPoints(double[]xs, double[]ys){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.x=xs.clone();
        this.y=ys.clone();
        frame.add(new PlotPoints());
        frame.setSize(100, 100);//laptop display size
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Here is the other class that invokes the 'drawPoints' method from the PlotPoints Class. I got this code snippet from some StackOverflow Q&As, and tried to improvise on it to suit my needs. If a different structure is more suited, I'd be grateful for your sharing.

```
import java.lang.*;
public class MainClass {
double[] xcoords;
double[] ycoords;
public static void main(String[] args){
    //create instances of classes
    PlotPoints myPlots=new PlotPoints();
    MainClass myMain=new MainClass();

    //initialize coordinates
    myMain.xcoords=new double[5];
    myMain.ycoords=new double[5];

    //put values into coordinates
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        myMain.xcoords[i]=Math.random()*1000; //Random number 
        myMain.ycoords[i]=Math.random()*1000;
    }

    //Create a plotter. Plot
    //to draw points defined by: (xcoords[i],ycoords[i])
    myPlots.drawPoints(myMain.xcoords, myMain.ycoords);

    //Please do this!       
}
```

}

Comment: `"Any chance I could do this without 'redrawing' the canvas?"` -- why not re-draw the component, or here, you would be simply calling `repaint()`?

Answer (score 3):

> Any chance I could do this without 'redrawing' the canvas?

Sure.  Draw them to a `BufferedImage` that is itself displayed in a `JLabel`.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628553/418556).

[image]

But don't be too quick to go this way.  Java-2D can animate thousands of graphics elements in a `paint()` method.